# Is it fine to be lazy at inserting in Android SQLiteDatabase having a unique column?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am aware that if I set a column in a table to be unique, I can prevent other records from being added with the same value on that column. What I would like to know is if it's of good practice to leave it like that. I have seen there is a sql warning, but I am not sure if that affects the app in any way.

Comment: I'll preface this with the fact that I've never used Android SQL before but I have used SQL in other situations. If I understand, requiring unique value involves "one-to-one" relationship, such as "one person-to-one birthdate"; allowing non-unique values involves "one-to-many" relationship, such as "one person-to-many hobbies". So it's a matter of what you need to happen and control. But I don't know why there'd be a warning, so maybe I don't understand the situation. What is the warning?

Comment: You don't get a warning; trying to insert a non-unique value result in an *error*. You have to decide yourself if this, and its consequences, result in the correct behaviour for your app.

Comment: Thank for your comments, and yes DSlomer64 this shouldn't be a biggie on sql. I do see this error on my log..Error inserting issue=1.2 title=android for ios location=/development/android/zippy.zip datetime=2015-08-03 12:42:08 file_location=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: magazines.issue (code 2067)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides insertOrThrow. In my first insert query I was just assuring a column to be unique and prevent to be inserted multiple times and that didn't have any issues with crashing the app. In my second attempt I used a constraint for a few columns then that error did crash my app.

So best thing to do is

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

try{
    db.insertOrThrow(SQLMagazine.TABLE, null, values);
}
catch(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```